# SQL Server Left Join issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

When I execute this:

```
SELECT i.descricao, 
       sii.quantidade           quantidade_inicial, 
       sii.quantidade * i.valor valor_inicial
FROM   itensvalor i 
       LEFT JOIN saldoinicialprodutositens sii 
              ON i.id = sii.iditemvalor 
                 AND Isnull(sii.datahoraexclusao, '') = '' 
WHERE  sii.idSaldoInicialProduto IN (SELECT id FROM saldoInicialProdutos WHERE idmovimentodiario = 76)
```

It returns this:

[image]

And when I execute this:

```
SELECT i.descricao, 
       sfi.quantidade           quantidade_final, 
       sfi.quantidade * i.valor valor_final 
FROM   itensvalor i 
       LEFT JOIN saldofinalprodutositens sfi 
              ON i.id = sfi.iditemvalor 
                 AND Isnull(sfi.datahoraexclusao, '') = '' 
WHERE    sfi.idSaldoFinalProduto IN (SELECT id FROM saldoFinalProdutos WHERE idmovimentodiario = 76)
```

It returns this: (with the R$100,00)

[image]

But, finally, when I try to join the 2 tables, the value that refers to R$100,00 not appears.

I'm trying to join using this query:

```
SELECT i.descricao, 
       sii.quantidade           quantidade_inicial, 
       sii.quantidade * i.valor valor_inicial, 
       sfi.quantidade           quantidade_final, 
       sfi.quantidade * i.valor valor_final 
FROM   itensvalor i 
       LEFT JOIN saldofinalprodutositens sfi 
              ON i.id = sfi.iditemvalor 
                 AND Isnull(sfi.datahoraexclusao, '') = '' 
       LEFT JOIN saldoinicialprodutositens sii 
              ON i.id = sii.iditemvalor 
                 AND Isnull(sii.datahoraexclusao, '') = '' 
WHERE  sii.idSaldoInicialProduto IN (SELECT id FROM saldoInicialProdutos WHERE idmovimentodiario = 76)
AND    sfi.idSaldoFinalProduto IN (SELECT id FROM saldoFinalProdutos WHERE idmovimentodiario = 76)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move your WHERE inside the ON clause for that to work:

```
SELECT i.descricao, 
       sii.quantidade           quantidade_inicial, 
       sii.quantidade * i.valor valor_inicial, 
       sfi.quantidade           quantidade_final, 
       sfi.quantidade * i.valor valor_final 
FROM   itensvalor i 
       LEFT JOIN saldofinalprodutositens sfi 
              ON i.id = sfi.iditemvalor 
                 AND Isnull(sfi.datahoraexclusao, '') = '' 
                 and sfi.idSaldoFinalProduto IN (SELECT id FROM saldoFinalProdutos WHERE idmovimentodiario = 76)
       LEFT JOIN saldoinicialprodutositens sii 
              ON i.id = sii.iditemvalor 
                 AND Isnull(sii.datahoraexclusao, '') = '' 
                 and sii.idSaldoInicialProduto IN (SELECT id FROM saldoInicialProdutos WHERE idmovimentodiario = 76)
```

Otherwise, your  `sfi.idSaldoFinalProduto` is null, and the row is omited.

Comment: Moving the WHERE inside the ON caluse solved my problem. Thanks!